# How to delete a row that has the same ID as a variable in an SQLite database

Tags: sqlite

I've got a function that I'd like use to delete a row in my database. This is the only way I've used the DELETE statement to remove a row before but I want the 1 to be replaced by a variable called recID so that the value of recID is the row ID number which is deleted. So if recID = 6, I want the function to delete the row with ID = 6. I hope that makes sense.

```
'DELETE FROM MyRecords WHERE ID=1';
```

The notation I've been using is the following, if it helps or makes any difference.

```
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql(     //DELETE STATEMENT HERE     );
});
```

Comment: Parameterised query is what you want, probably. SQlite doesn't affect that much, which programming language you are using might.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm using Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`executeSql` supports arguments (check [definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#dom-sqltransaction-executesql)).

Use it like:

```
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql("DELETE FROM MyRecords WHERE ID=?", [recId]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain that your variable, `recID`, will only ever contain numbers, you can just use:

```
transaction.executeSql("DELETE FROM MyRecords WHERE ID=" + recID);
```

If recID comes from outside your application (user input) however, it either needs to be sanitized, or use a prepared statement and use the database API to set the parameter after the statement has been prepared.  Otherwise you open yourself up to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

I don't know the details of your SQLite wrapper, or what version of SQLite it wraps, but creating a prepared statement using the SQLite3 C API would go something like this:

```
// sqlite3* db = ...
sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "DELETE FROM MyRecords WHERE ID=?", -1, &stmt, 0);
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, recID);
sqlite3_step();
// ...
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

This simple example excludes all the error checking you'd want to do in a real application, but since you're using a wrapper that has different syntax anyway, you'd have to figure out how it wraps these functions anyway.